# Failed to find zero weight by GradientDescentOptimizer

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, regression

I tried to build a regression model to train my dataset via TensorFlow. When it is W1*x^2 + W2*x + b, it shows nan; when it is W2*x + b, it can output figures. Why can't W1=0 be found? Is there anything wrong in my model buidling logic?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import csv
import re
import datetime
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.01
training_epochs = 2000

# Training Data
data_X = [  0.,   2.,   5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.,  12.,  13.,  14.]
data_Y = [ 2568.300049,  2540.100098,  2552.399902,  2583.899902,  2607.100098,
  2603.300049,  2561.699951,  2614.899902,  2590.800049,  2578.199951]
train_X = numpy.asarray(data_X)
train_Y = numpy.asarray(data_Y)
n_samples = train_X.shape[0]

# Model parameters
rng = numpy.random
W1 = tf.Variable([rng.randn()], dtype=tf.float32, name="weight1")
# OK when W1 = tf.constant(0.)
W2 = tf.Variable([rng.randn()], dtype=tf.float32, name="weight2")
b = tf.Variable([rng.randn()], dtype=tf.float32, name="bias")
# Model input and output
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
linear_model = W1*tf.square(x) + W2*x + b

# loss
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(linear_model - y))/(2*n_samples)
# optimizer
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)

# training loop
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
# Start training
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init) # reset values to wrong
    for i in range(training_epochs):
        sess.run(train, {x: train_X, y: train_Y})
    # evaluate training accuracy
    curr_W1, curr_W2, curr_b, curr_loss = sess.run([W1, W2, b, loss], {x: train_X, y: train_Y})
    print("W1: %s W2: %s b: %s loss: %s"%(curr_W1, curr_W2, curr_b, curr_loss))

    # Graphic display
    plt.plot(train_X, train_Y, 'ro', label='Original data')
    plt.plot(train_X, sess.run(W1) * numpy.square(train_X) + sess.run(W2) * train_X + sess.run(b), label='Fitted line')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yoel Zeldes is correct.  However, such a simple problem shouldn't require 2000000 training steps.  The reason it does here is first because a quadratic model isn't a good match for apparently linear data, and second because the best solution requires a huge bias value, which takes a long time to learn because the impact of changes to `b` are dwarfed by the impact of changes to `W1`.

A good way to deal with this is through rescaling the data.  If you include the lines

```
train_X = (train_X - numpy.mean(train_X)) / (numpy.amax(train_X) - numpy.amin(train_X))
train_Y = (train_Y - numpy.mean(train_Y)) / (numpy.amax(train_Y) - numpy.amin(train_Y))`
```

then your data will have a mean of 0 and a range of 1, and it will be much easier to train with either model.  Note that if you want to test your trained model on new data points, you'll need to scale them by the same amount.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your solution can work and run fast. Question: since X is a time-based series and the values afterward will increment; Y is supposed (but not necessarily) to have larger values than training data. How can I adjust the scaling?

Comment: If I understand what you're asking then you shouldn't need to do anything.  Your model is learning parameters that should work for future data.  You do have very little training data, so your model probably won't be very accurate for data far in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: your learning rate is too big. Use something smaller (~0.0001) and use more epochs (~2000000).

Long answer: W1 is NaN because during the training its magnitude got bigger and bigger until we got numerical issues which resulted in NaN. You can observe it by adding W1 into the fetch list you pass to `sess.run()`.

Moreover, you can see its sign keeps changing, which is a sign of overshoot (no pun intended). Indeed, if you add the error `linear_model - y` to the fetch list, you'll also its sign keeps changing too. This can happen when your learning rate is too big.

After playing around with different learning rates (and compensating with more epochs), I got the following:

When W1 is fixed to 0:
W1: 0.0 W2: [ 4.70993948] b: [ 2539.71435547] loss: 237.369
This will be our baseline.

learning_rate = 0.001: 
Still NaN.

learning_rate = 0.0001 
training_epochs = 200000 
W1: [-2.63166738] W2: [ 50.53411484] b: [ 2375.20996094] loss: 2317.36

learning_rate = 0.0001 
training_epochs = 2000000 
W1: [-0.3543286] W2: [ 8.49937725] b: [ 2541.46655273] loss: 189.766

So the last one might be what you want, since its loss is comparable with the baseline. However, you should experiment with it and find the best values.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your solution can work but take a long time to run.